# Помогите отобразить правильно компонент в Angular WEB App

Tags: html, typescript, scss, angular

Вот ссылка на последний комит: https://github.com/AlelekovEvgeny/CarefulClinic/commit/e8620a7b8d4e191015ac2480b77843dba3a1bc95 
Задача была следующая: из  страницы list-prophylactic.component.html нужно переместить ссылку на sidenav.upload.data.component.html в страницу header.component.html. В целом мне это удалось, но с косяком. На картинке слева исходный вариант, а справа то что я сделал. Я предполагаю, что в моём варианте страница загрузки открывается внутри компонента главного меню. Как сделать, что бы она открылась так, как было в исходном варианте? (см. картинку)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вряд ли кто-то кроме вас будет полностью разбирать тот шаблон и смотреть где-что пропущено))

Comment: Эх... front-end сложна..) я просто на back учился, а угораздило взяться за проект, где требуется full stack сопровождение..) может кто даст какие общие намётки? Как там происходит эта магия во фронте? о_О

Answer (score -1):

поправил всё в scss файле (сделал высоту компонента загрузки 200%). конечно не лучшее решение, но на данном этапе норм.